I get invalid token error when trying to verify id token with firebase
I am trying to pass a token from my react app to the flask server so I can verify it.
this is the flask route
@app.route("/tasks", methods=["GET"])
def get_tasks():
    try:
        id_token = request.headers.get("Authorization").split(" ")[1]
        print(id_token)
        # Verify the ID token while checking if the token is revoked by
        # passing check_revoked=True.
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        print(decoded_token)
        # Token is valid and not revoked.
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
    except auth.RevokedIdTokenError as e:
        # Token revoked, inform the user to reauthenticate or signOut().
        return jsonify('RevokedIdTokenError')
    except auth.UserDisabledError as e:
        # Token belongs to a disabled user record.
        return jsonify('UserDisabledError')
    except auth.InvalidIdTokenError as e:
        # Token is invalid
        return jsonify('InvalidIdTokenError')

and this is the react part
async function getTaskName() {
    try {
      const userToken = await getToken()
      const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks',{
        method : 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}` // Include token in Authorization header
        }
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
      //setTask(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching task:', error);
    }
  }

I checked if the userToken is type of string on both ends
I printed in the console both tokens and they are both identical
I printed the error from the exception, see it below, however my computer clock is set to automatic and it seems correct
Token used too early, 1711964786 < 1711964789. Check that your computer's clock is set correctly.

Is your computer time correct?

yes it's set to automatic and it displays the right time
